# JDOM2 and XPath

Tags: java, xml, xpath, jdom

When I run the following

```
XPathFactory xpathFactory = XPathFactory.instance();
XPathExpression<Double> query =
xpathFactory.compile("count(1)", Filters.fdouble());
List<Double> result = query.evaluate(new Element("test"));
```

yet the evaluation fails:

Unable to evaluate expression. See cause
Cause: Function :count

That is a bit nonsense example, but I wanted something self contained. What is wrong with this?

Comment: `count` expects an `item()*` element as argument, but 1 is a `xs:integer`.

Comment: @dirkk, item() is the most generic type in the type system, so passing an integer (which is a sequence of one integer) is perfectly valid and should return 1, count((1,2)) should return 2 etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count the number of `test` elements, try this;

```
Element root = new Element("test");
Document doc = new Document(root);

XPathFactory xpathFactory = XPathFactory.instance();
XPathExpression<Double> query = xpathFactory.compile("count(//test)", Filters.fdouble());
List<Double> result = query.evaluate(doc);
```

Comment: I tried this (I am using org.jdom2 2.0.4) and I am still getting the same error.  Unable to evaluate expression. See cause | UnresolvableException | Function :count.